# How to manipulate a POP3 message?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, pop3

The mail store used is POP3 :

```
mail.storeType=pop3s
mail.host=pop.moov.mg
mail.port=995
mail.username=somemail
mail.password=somepassword
mail.auth=true
mail.ssl.trust=*
```

I want to retrieve e-mails, then mark them, but I cannot mark them :

```
public POP3Store getEmailStore() throws Exception {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", storeType);
    properties.setProperty("mail." + storeType + ".host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail." + storeType + ".port", String.valueOf(port));
    properties.setProperty("mail." + storeType + ".auth", String.valueOf(auth));
    properties.setProperty("mail." + storeType + ".socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("mail." + storeType + ".ssl.trust", sss_trust);
    try {
         Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
         POP3Store emailStore = (POP3Store) emailSession.getStore(storeType);
         return emailStore;
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         throw e;
    }
}

private POP3Store emailstore = null;
emailstore = getEmailStore();
Folder emailFolder = emailstore.getFolder("INBOX");
emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
if (messages != null) {
  for (Message message : messages) {
    if (message.getHeader("eeeee") == null || !Arrays.asList(message.getHeader("eeeee")).contains("ticket created")) {
      try {
         mailService.createTicket(message);
         mailService.mark(message);
      } catch (Exception ex) {
         throw ex;
      }
    }
  }
}
System.out.println("FIN Receving");
emailFolder.close(true);
```

code of mailService.mark :

```
public void mark(Message message) throws MessagingException {
        try {
            message.setHeader("eeeee", "ticket created");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

At runtime I get `IllegalWriteException POP3 messages are read-only`

So how to manipulate the message ?

Comment: I think in POP3, you don’t. You would have to separately keep a cache of which messages have been read

Comment: but I do not know if a message was read !

Comment: If you want to modify messages, you need to use IMAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[POP3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) is an old protocol for *retrieving* messages. It is meant to be used to download messages with the idea that the retrieved messages are immediately deleted from the server, similarly to how a physical mailbox works.

It simply doesn't offer mechanism for manipulating messages.